# Boolean variable always assuming 1 in select...into - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, boolean

I'm doing a stored procedure to update a table and that table has a boolean named: "Finished", as a field. This field informs us if a game is finished. In my problem it makes sense to be able to set something as finished before the expiration date so, because of that, I'm checking if the row to update has the "Finished" field as true or if the expiration date has passed.

```
SET @isFinished=0;
SELECT Finished INTO @isFinished FROM game WHERE ID = gameID; 
-- gameID comes as a parameter
-- date comes as a parameter as well
IF DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d") , CURDATE()) < 0  OR @isFinished<>0 THEN
    select CONCAT("Game can't be updated because it's already finished. Days missing:",DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), CURDATE() )," and @finished=", @isFinished, ", game=",gameID)
    into @msg;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF;
```

The problem is that when I try to update an unfinished game it is getting into the if and throwing the error message: 
"sqlMessage: 'Game can\'t be updated because it\'s already finished. Days missing:337 and @finished=1, game=2'".
**quick note: The variable @isFinished is never used but in this block of code.**

I've always assured that the value of "Finished" was 0 before I tested it and yet it keeps selecting it as 1 and, because of that, getting into the if.
I thought it could be from the select...into so I tried it out of the stored procedure (literally copy paste, just changed the "gameID" to the actual ID that I'm using) and it worked perfectly.

```
SELECT Finished INTO @isFinished FROM game WHERE ID = 2;
SELECT @isFinished
```

After this, I don't know what more can I check. If anyone could help I'd be thankful.

**Isolated test:**

```
create database test;
use test;

create table Tournament(
    ID int(10) not null unique auto_increment,
    Name varchar(250) not null,
    Start_Date date not null,
    End_Date date not null,
    Primary key(ID)
);

create table Game(
    ID int(10) not null unique auto_increment,
    Tournament_ID int(10),
    Date date,
    Finished boolean,
    Foreign Key(Tournament_ID) references Tournament(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Primary Key(ID)
);

INSERT INTO Tournament VALUES(NULL, "tournament1", str_to_date("2020-06-01","%Y-%m-%d"), str_to_date("2020-07-01","%Y-%m-%d"));
INSERT INTO Game VALUES(NULL, 1, str_to_date("2020-06-02","%Y-%m-%d"), 0);

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UpdateGame`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdateGame`(IN gameID int, date varchar(10), finished boolean)
BEGIN
SET @isFinished=0;
SELECT Finished INTO @isFinished FROM game WHERE ID = gameID;

IF DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d") , CURDATE()) < 0  OR @isFinished<>0 THEN
    select CONCAT("Game can't be updated because it's already finished. Days missing:",DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), CURDATE() )," and @finished=", @isFinished, ", game=",gameID)
    into @msg;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF;
UPDATE game SET Date=STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), Finished=finished WHERE ID=gameID;
END$$
call UpdateGame(1,"2020-06-03",1);

SELECT * FROM game;

SELECT Finished INTO @isFinished FROM game WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT @isFinished;
```

Comment: MySQL does not have boolean data type (so enum, tinyint 0/1 or CHAR with different values are used quite often). So what is `Finished` date type? What is `date` date type? If it is DATE, why you using STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: @fifonik `Finished` is a tinyint(1). `date` is a param from the stored procedure, it comes as varchar.

Comment: Can you create an isolated test? Like table create + insert + SP create + SP call? I tried to re-create steps you mentioned and everything works fine. I think it will work fine in isolated test for you as well as the steps are pretty basic and you will need to find out what is going on in your real env. The only idea is you are checking wrong game record.

Comment: @fifonik Just attached it to the question. I tried this before I post it but I got the same error message. Thanks for the help, by the way!

Comment: This explains your issue. You have finished in param so in your `SELECT Finished INTO @isFinished FROM game WHERE ID = gameID;` you are selecting the in param instead of `game`.`Finished`. So remove the param of use `table`.`column` syntax in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have IN param `Finished` so inside your stored procedure, when querying the table, in fact you querying the IN param.

So you need to delete/rename the `Finished` IN param or write your internal select query as:

```
SELECT `game`.`Finished` 
INTO @isFinished 
FROM game 
WHERE ID = gameID;
```

P.S. People usually have some kind of prefixes on input params to distinguish them visually inside the stored procedure from tables, columns of local variables.

Comment: That makes much sense. Thought that, as I was selecting from game, the variables names conflict wouldn't matter. I tried your way and worked fine! So this answer as my upvote, for those who maybe intersted

Comment: Feel free to press the button to accept this answer ;)